# HG pull and merge remote named branch

Tags: merge, mercurial, branch

Suppose I have a branch called `test` on remote server. All of the people working with this repository have this branch too. We all make some local commits to it and somehow the remote version becomes changed. Now, I want to merge remote named branch `test` into my local branch `test` having my current work saved. So if my current branch is default I do:

```
hg update -C test

make some changes in test branch

hg commit -m "Some changes"
hg pull
hg merge
hg commit -m "Merge"
hg push
```

However I recieve strange error during some of those steps: abort: branch 'test' has one head - please merge with an explicit rev
(run 'hg heads' to see all heads)

Why is that?

Comment: Please give a clear outline of how and when the error occurs. "I get an error somewhere" doesn't cut it. Are you sure the remote is even different? Sounds like there is nothing to merge with on the `test` branch.

Comment: Try `hg heads` after the `hg pull` to see if there are other heads to merge, sounds there is not as @DanMan comments. Also an `hg log -G -T "{rev} {desc}" -r "branch(test)"` could help.